# BeautifulSoup remove tags followed by specific tag and specific attribute

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm new in this world of web scraping and so far I've been amazed with BeautifulSoup. However, there's something I wasn't able to do.

What I want to do is to remove some tags which are followed with some specific tag and specific attribute.

Let me show you:

```
#Import modules
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#Parse URL
url = "http://www.soccervista.com/Italy-Serie_A-2016_2017-845699.html"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

#This is the table which I want to extract
table = soup.find_all('table')[4]
```

After obtaining the correct table which I want to manipulate, there are some 'tr' tags which are followed by 'td' and attribute 'colspan'

What I finally want is to remove those specific 'tr' because there are more 'tr' tags which I need.

The total of 'td' with 'colspan' attribute are 3:

```
#Output for 'td' with 'colspan'

print(table.select('td[colspan]'))

[<td colspan="13"><img height="10" src="/imgs/line.png" width="100%"/></td>,
 <td colspan="13"><img height="10" src="/imgs/line.png" width="100%"/></td>,
 <td colspan="13"><img height="10" src="/imgs/line.png" width="100%"/></td>]
```

And here is a extract from the HTML and one example of the specific 'tr' which I want to remove (Inserted a Note below saying "#THIS ONE!"):

```
 <td align="center">
    2:1
   </td>
   <td class="one">
    AC Milan
   </td>
   <td>
    <a href="/Cagliari-AC_Milan-2320071-2320071.html">
     <img alt="More details about  -  soccer game" border="0" height="14" src="/imgs/detail3.gif" width="14"/>
    </a>
   </td>
  </tr>
  ***<tr class="predict"> ------------- >>> **#THIS ONE!*****
   <td colspan="13">
    <img height="10" src="/imgs/line.png" width="100%"/>
   </td>
   <tr class="predict">
    <td>
     27 May
    </td>
    <td>
     38
    </td>
    <td>
     FT
    </td>
    <td align="right" class="one">
```

By the way, I would like to remove 'td colspan' and 'img' as well.

Any ideas?

*Python latest version installed

*BeautifulSoup module latest version installed

Comment: Clearly state which `tr` tags you want to delete.

Comment: Sorry @MD.KhairulBasar, the three 'tr' tags are the ones like this:

Comment: `<tr class="predict">` but the problem is there are a lot of them....and I want those which are followed by these: `<td colspan="13">
    <img height="10" src="/imgs/line.png" width="100%"/>` @MD.KhairulBasar

Comment: I've updated my answer and it works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already got the `table` and `td[colspan]`, then you can get the `td`'s `parent` element then [decompose](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) it from `table`, and change the parser from `html.parser` to `lxml` like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#Parse URL
url = "http://www.soccervista.com/Italy-Serie_A-2016_2017-845699.html"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml') #change the parser from html.parser to lxml

#This is the table which I want to extract
table = soup.find_all('table')[4]
for tdcol in table.select('td[colspan]'):
    tdcol.parent.decompose()
print table.prettify()
```

then `table` will delete the items:

```
<tr class="predict"><td colspan="13"><img height="10" src="/imgs/line.png" width="100%"/></td></tr>
<tr class="predict"><td colspan="13"><img height="10" src="/imgs/line.png" width="100%"/></td></tr>
<tr class="predict"><td colspan="13"><img height="10" src="/imgs/line.png" width="100%"/></td></tr>
```

Comment: This looks what I want...Actually it deletes those, but the rest of the information is deleted too! Is there a way to keep the rest of the information? @Tiny.D

Comment: What I want to delete are just three 'tr' tags and are like this: `<tr class="predict">` but the problem is there are a lot of them....and I want those which are followed by these: `<td colspan="13"> <img height="10" src="/imgs/line.png" width="100%"/>` @Tiny.D

Comment: In additon, something weird is happening. When I run the for loop, I get this message: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decompose'`. But when I run it again, then the rest of the information deletes. @Tiny.D

Comment: This is excatly what I wanted. Thank you @Tiny.D The question is...Why "lxml" instead of "html.parser"? Need to figure it out!

Answer (score 3):

Find the specific tags you want to delete and then use [deompose()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) or [extract()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract).

```
for tag in tags_to_delete:
    tag.decompose()
```

Or

```
for tag in tags_to_delete:
    tag.extract()
```

**EDIT**

To find the specific tags you can first find all the `tr` tags and then check if that tag has a `td` with attribute `colspan="13"` if yes then `decompose()` it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.soccervista.com/Italy-Serie_A-2016_2017-845699.html"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

table = soup.find_all('table')[4]    
for t in table.find_all("tr", class_="predict"):

    check = t.find("td", colspan="13")
    if(check != None):
        t.decompose()
```

Comment: Amazing! This works perfectly! @MD.KhairulBasar The question is, why "lxml" instead of "html.parser"?

Comment: @EdmundoWright The reasons I used `lxml` parser are `lxml` is recommended to use in official documentation of `BeautifulSoup`. `lxml` is faster than `html.parser`. and `lxml` fixes html format if the html isn't well-formed.