# Python/BeautifulSoup: How do I stop treating a list of elements like a single element?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new to Python, and to BeautifulSoup. I'm trying to parse some datasets from a state vendor, which they export in badly-formed HTML. I've successfully gotten one file parsed and exported to CSV, so I was feeling pretty good. On another HTML file, however, the vendor decided to split the data out into multiple tables, separated by wide `<td colspan>` "header" groups. I have attached a redacted screenshot (at bottom) in case anyone has a better idea about what to do than what I am trying:

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup's decompose() to discard those colspan tags completely, thereby joining the data into one big table that I can parse. In order to find those colspans and decompose them, I'm using some code suggested [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44711916/beautifulsoup-remove-tags-followed-by-specific-tag-and-specific-attribute), and getting an error, and I am too ignorant to figure out how to get this working.

```
with open ("file.html") as fp:
soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html5lib', from_encoding="us-ascii")#, parse_only=SoupStrainer('td'))

table = soup.find_all('table')
for tdcol in table.select('td[colspan]'):
    tdcol.parent.decompose()
    
print(table)
```

is returning `AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'select'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?`

**My question:** would someone be kind enough to explain to me what this error means, and what I need to do to address it? I've read the documentation. I've read Stack Overflow posts. I know I'm just not understanding something fundamental. I would really appreciate some helpful guidance.

[Redacted screenshot of split tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2Ce0.png)

Comment: `table` is a list (or list like - not sure off the top of my head) when you assign it with `find_all`.  In the next line you treat it like it's not a list, with table.select.  i'd use something like `for table in soup.find_all('tr'): for tdcol in table.select(...): `

Comment: oh, also, you aren't finding tables, you are finding "tr"s.

Comment: Ah, embarrassing: copied the wrong version of my attempts in. I get the same error with table as tr. Will fix main post.

Answer (score 0):

[keithpjolley's answer works for me]

table is a list (or list like - not sure off the top of my head) when you assign it with find_all. In the next line you treat it like it's not a list, with table.select. i'd use something like for table in soup.find_all('tr'): for tdcol in table.select(...): –
keithpjolley

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).